# substring before special character and replace it by corresponding special characters

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I m working on SMS related module where i need to send sms to consumer in encrypted manner like : 
**"The OTP sent to the number *******632 and email id jac********@gmail.com."**
I took care of mobile number but i want to encrypt email id in below manner

```
jacknjill356@gmail.com 
to
jac********@gmail.com
```

but the solution i found is not optimal...
i observe 
"jac" is one string and 
'@gmail.com' as second string and 
the third left part i replace by special characters "*", and i concatenated all three but its not good programming practice.

is there any way to do it with regex concept, so i just want to replace string before '@' symbol.
please suggest me the best one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick :

```
String email = "myemailadress@gmail.com";
System.out.println(email.replaceAll("(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]", "$1*"));

//Output : mye********@gmail.com
```

Comment: Outstanding, that's exactly i am looking for, hey can you explain the regex, regex is quite new for me, it will be the pleasure, if u explain a bit about your regex expression. thanks